# Redirecting Standardoutput with Powershell class in .net

Tags: c#, powershell

i am currently trying to get the standardoutput of a program I run via Powershell.

I have something like this:

```
                    using var ps = PowerShell.Create();
                    ps.AddCommand("Start-Process")
                        .AddParameter("FilePath", somePath)
                        .AddParameter("ArgumentList", someArguments)
                        .AddParameter(...); //Adding some more parameters

                    var result = ps.Invoke<Process>();
                    result[0].StandardOutput //Always null
```

Now I want to get the Standardoutput but I dont seem to be able to get it.
The resulting Process has a public property "StandardOutput" but it is always null.

I know I can get this to work by adding a full Powershell script with AddScript instead of the other functions provided by the Powershell class.

```
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "SomeFileName"
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = "someArguments"
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
Write-Host $stdout
```

I dont want to do this though because in my use case i am building those commands with parameters as needed and I dont want to resort to string operations to build my commands.

Comment: Can you show us "some more parameters"? The parameter arguments passed to `Start-Process` are pretty important here...

Comment: The following may be of interest: [PowerShell.AddParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddParameters?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0)

Comment: `Start-Process` doesn't produce output, it offers this thru the `-RedirectStandard*` parameters to redirect to a file. If you need output from your process you should use the `Process` class in your C# code as you're doing in your pwsh code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Start-Process` doesn't produce output, it offers this through the `-RedirectStandard*` parameters to redirect output to a file. If you need output from your process you should use the `Process` Class in your C# code as you're doing in your PowerShell code. Probably should leave a PowerShell instance out of the equation too as there is no need for it unless you want to make use of [`WriteError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.writeerror?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0).

Another option could be running the process synchronously using the [`&` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-) in your PowerShell instance script.

Both methods are very rough examples for you to test, you should definitely implement error handling and other features if needed.

Save the definition in a PowerShell variable, i.e. `$def`:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace Testing
{
    public static class Test
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> RunWithProcess(string fileName, string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                FileName = fileName,
                Arguments = string.Join(" ", args)
            };

            using (Process proc = new Process { StartInfo = psi })
            {
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();

                while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    yield return proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }

        public static Collection<PSObject> RunWithPwsh(string fileName, string[] args)
        {
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                return ps.AddScript(@"
                    param($process, $arguments)

                    & $process @arguments")
                .AddParameter("process", fileName)
                .AddParameter("arguments", args)
                .Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $def

[Testing.Test]::RunWithPwsh('cmd.exe', ('/c', 'ping -n 10 google.com'))
[Testing.Test]::RunWithProcess('cmd.exe', ('/c', 'ping -n 10 google.com'))
```

Comment: This sums up everything I wanted to know. Thank you very much.
I kind of wanted to use the Powershell class due to what I have to implement but i think i can work out a solution where that is not necessary. I will go with the Process class in c#